# how to handle new Error() in node.js using ES6 Symbol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a endpoint in node.js using ES6 Symbol. Example

// ES6 Symbol Method

```
const taskCreationMethod = {
    [Symbol.taskMethod]() {
        return {
            storeCheckFunc: async function(storeId, employeeId) {
                let store = await resourceModel["stores"].findById(storeId).populate(references["stores"]);
                if(!store) {
                    return new Error("Store not found");
                }
                let employeeCheck = _.find(store.employees, (empObj) => {
                    return empObj._id == employeeId
                })
                if(!employeeCheck) {
                    return new Error("Employee not found");
                }
                return employeeCheck;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

//end point

```
 export const taskCreation = async(req, res) => {
            const storeCheck = await taskCreationMethod[Symbol.taskMethod]().storeCheckFunc(req.body.store, req.body.assigned_to);
      // here How can I handle return with Error Response?
 }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  `async` functions would typically return errors by throwing (which will reject the promise that the function returned) or by manually returning a rejected promise.

Comment: Use `try` and `catch` to catch error thrown.

Comment: @jfriend00  Here I return all the result with new Error(); how can I handle this Error response after I process..

Comment: I tried in also try and catch in endpoint

Comment: Do you understand the basic error reporting model of promises?  If not, go read up because an `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise that is rejected with an error or resolved with a value.  Pick one of those and use it for every possible return situation.  For errors, you should be rejecting the promise which can be done either with `throw new Error(...)` or `return Promise.reject(new Error(...))`.  Then the caller would use `someFunc().then().catch()` to get the value or see the error.  Please go read about errors and promises.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `throw` that error not just `return` it if you want to use the mechanisms of error handling. The thrown error will become a rejected promise which you can then handle with `.catch()` directly on the promise or with `try/catch` if you are using it in an async function. Here's a simplified example:

```js
function populate() {
  // always resolves to undefined
  return Promise.resolve(undefined)
}

const taskCreationMethod = {
  someMethod() {
    return {
      storeCheckFunc: async function() {
        let store = await populate()          // always resolves undefined
        if (!store) {                         // so it always fails
          throw new Error("Store not found"); // throw error
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

// regular promise then().catch()
taskCreationMethod.someMethod().storeCheckFunc()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log("Error:", err.message)) // catch

// OR … async function
async function runit() {
  try {
    let s = await taskCreationMethod.someMethod().storeCheckFunc()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err.message)
  }
}

runit()
```